# One word synonymous to display of power

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, verbs, nouns

I need one single word that is synonymous to "bold display of power/might/hold/domination in some place" .It would be much appreciated if someone can provide me a noun otherwise a verb will also do it.

Comment: Not a single word, but the phrase [*show of force*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/show-of-force) is often used. Similarly, *shock and awe* and *shot across the bow*.

Comment: Muscle flexing.

Answer (score 1):

Tour de force

> A feat or display of strength, skill, or ingenuity

per Webster's

Answer (score 1):

You could consider:

- **[Ostentation](http://www.tfd.com/ostentation):**

> Pretentious display meant to impress others; pretentious showiness.
>
> Archaic The act or an instance of showing; an exhibition.

- **[Spectacle](http://www.tfd.com/spectacle)**:

> A public performance or display, especially one on a large or lavish
> scale.

- **[Bravado](http://www.tfd.com/bravado)**:

> vaunted display of courage or self-confidence; swagger

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context, consider:

[***parade***](http://www.ushmm.org/wlc/en/media_fi.php?MediaId=200)

> An ostentatious show; an exhibition [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parade)

***grandstand play***

> *noun phrase*
>
> 1. A play made with special brilliance and brio, esp in order to impress the spectators.
> 2. Any action, speech, tactic, etc, designed to appeal to spectators; a tour de force : *The President's pronouncement's just a grandstand play*(1888+ Baseball)
>    [The Dictionary of American Slang, Fourth Edition by Barbara Ann Kipfer, PhD. and Robert L. Chapman, PhD.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grandstand-play)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, to conquer, to subjugate or to master.  A noun - maybe elite? blowhard?

Comment: None of these are synonymous with a **Display** of power